# Column ambigously defined when using Pivot with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I am trying to run this pivot query to show the dates as columns which are in this format: "MM/DD/YYYY" and the occurrences of some kind of ID's in each date:

The column which contains the dates is "DATE_POSTED" -- DATA TYPE date
The column which contains the ID's is "ID_INST" -- DATA TYPE varchar2

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID_INST, DATE_POSTED
      FROM total.table1) PIVOT XML (COUNT (DATE_POSTED)
                                           FOR (DATE_POSTED)
                                           IN  (SELECT distinct DATE_POSTED
                                                  FROM total.table1));
```

The error which i'm receiving is ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined, I did some searches but I keep getting this error. Not sure if my approach is totally correct. P.S im using XML keyword due to the fact that it prompted: missing keyword

Current table: [image: Current table]

Expected result: [image: Expected Result]

Comment: PLease show your table definitions

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Have you tried `IN(ANY)`? I'm not getting the point here to use `IN (SELECT distinct DATE_POSTED FROM total.table1)`...

Comment: @Radagast81 lets just say this table has more columns, so I cannot search anywhere, I have to specifically search for ID's in dates

Comment: @D-Shih done, please check the question again, I've attached some sample screenshots

Comment: @LorikBerisha I think you are looking for dynamic pivot

Comment: @LorikBerisha the `ANY` keyword in this statement just means that you generate a column for any value of `DATE_POSTED` what is the same as your subselect. If you want to filter these dates you would do that in the inner subselect as well, so the `ANY` Keyword will get you what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID_INST, TO_CHAR(DATE_POSTED, 'DD-Mon')  DATE_POSTED
          FROM TOTAL.TABLE1)
  PIVOT XML (COUNT(DATE_POSTED)
             FOR DATE_POSTED IN (ANY))
```

The poblem might be caused by the fact, that date also stores time information additional to the date.

So you get different values for `DATE_POSTED`, but the conversion to char leads to the same column name as the date format mask cuts the time information.